# SCSI drive spinup after file descriptor is closed

Tags: c, linux, scsi

I have a program where a spindown is required of a drive which is not mounted or used in any other way.

I noticed that the drive autoamtically gets a spin up after I close the filedescriptor.

I have not found any information why this is, is there any way to disable this?

Here is a short program to test it yourself. Any help or pointers would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <scsi/sg.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    sg_io_hdr_t io_hdr;
    const unsigned char     stopcmdblk[6]        =     { 0x1B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("couldn't open device");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&io_hdr, 0, sizeof(sg_io_hdr_t));
    io_hdr.interface_id = 'S';
    io_hdr.cmd_len = 6;
    io_hdr.mx_sb_len = 32;
    io_hdr.dxfer_direction = SG_DXFER_NONE;
    io_hdr.dxfer_len = 0;
    io_hdr.dxferp = NULL;
    io_hdr.cmdp = malloc(6);
    io_hdr.sbp = calloc(32, 1);

    memcpy(io_hdr.cmdp, stopcmdblk, 6);

    errno = 0;
    int ret = ioctl(fd, SG_IO, &io_hdr);
    if (ret < 0) { 
        perror("ioctl error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((io_hdr.info & SG_INFO_OK_MASK) != SG_INFO_OK) {
        printf("SCSI err\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("finished spindown\n");

    sleep(30);

    printf("close file now\n");

    close(fd);
    printf("file closed\n");

    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Could it be that the filesystem maintains on the disk information about file locking (a hidden lock file or alike)? You open the file R/W so it must be locked. Other Linux nodes on the network accessing the disk can read this information to determine if they can safely access the file. Then, when you close the file, the spin-up is so the lock can be removed from the disk.

Comment: is it possible to force this lock after a file close? after the spin down the drive will be removed anyway

Answer (score 1):

I guess the system wants to write some metadata to disk when the file is closed. For example, the file size - it seems pointless to update the file size after each `write` call. So it's updated on the `close` call.

I think you need the [`sync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sync_(Unix)) system call. There is also a `fsync` variant that works for just one file; however, it's not about your file descriptor; you want to remove the drive, so *all* file descriptors should be taken care of.

Comment: that would be rather weird, since I never write anything to disk.

Comment: Maybe it writes something like "last access time for the file"?

Comment: that is written in the filesystem not directly to the device.

Comment: If you don't write anything, try open it read-only. See what happens.

Comment: I should also clarify that this disk is not mounted and shouldn`t be in use